# Implement zig-zag wordpress post loop structure

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I want to implement following zigzag div structure for WordPress post while loop...

My div structure as follows...

```
<div class=wrap>
  <div class='a'> Post 1 Content </div>
  <div class='b'> Post 2 Content </div>
</div>
<div class=wrap>
  <div class='b'> Post 3 Content </div>
  <div class='a'> Post 4 Content </div>
</div>
<div class=wrap>
  <div class='a'> Post 5 Content </div>
  <div class='b'> Post 6 Content </div>
</div>
<div class=wrap>
  <div class='b'> Post 7 Content </div>
  <div class='a'> Post 8 Content </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture of this structure? its not showing well

Answer (score 0):

The structure that you have mentioned is tricky one.

This can be possible with the following and its working as expected in my testing site.

This is working code that i have tested:

```
<?php
$args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'    => 8,
            );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ): 
    $post_count = 1;
    $wrapper_count = 1;
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        if( $post_count % 2 === 0 ): 
            $wrapper_count++;
            if( $wrapper_count % 2 != 0 ){ ?>
                <div class='a'> Post <?php echo $post_count; ?> Content </div>
            <?php
            } else{ ?>
                <div class='b'> Post <?php echo $post_count; ?> Content </div>
            <?php
            } ?>
            </div> <!-- .wrapper end -->
        <?php
        else: ?>
            <div class=wrap> <!-- wrapper start -->
        <?php
            if( $wrapper_count % 2 != 0 ){ ?>
                <div class='a'> Post <?php echo $post_count; ?> Content </div>
            <?php
            } else{ ?>
                <div class='b'> Post <?php echo $post_count; ?> Content </div>
            <?php
            }
        endif; 
        $post_count++;
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

I have made a loop as post query for now so that you can modify the code according your custom loop.

Please mention me if you still find any difficulty for understanding.

Thank You

Comment: working exactly I want, but the wrapper is not closing for odd number of posts.

Comment: @Samrat wrapper is closing in my testing, could you please show me the screenshot for better view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this can be easy to use in code for get the all posts.

```html
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 1;
$row1 = 'a';
$row2 = 'b';
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
<div class="posts">
 <?php
  foreach($posts as $post):
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    if($i % 2 == 0){ ?>
     <div class = "wrap">
     <?php } ?>
    <div class="<?php if($j % 2 == 1) { echo $row1; } else {echo $row2;} ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a> </div>
    <?php if($i % 2 == 1){ ?></div><?php } ?>
    <?php
      $j++;
     $i++;
  endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$classname = 'a';
while(have_posts()):the_post();
?>
    <div class=wrap>
        <div class=<?php echo $classname;?>>  Post Content  </div>
        <?php if($classname =='a')$classname = 'b';else $classname = 'a';?>
        <div class=<?php echo $classname;?>>  Post Content  </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
```

Comment: How can a post content be different inside a wrap element?